# What is considered as unethical omission of information on an application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, ethics

If someone were to have an opportunity to attend a school, and registered in courses, but was unable to attend due to personal issues, withdrew before the start of semester, never paid tuition, never attended courses, and is now reapplying to other schools, is this information relevant on an application? There would be no transcript to submit, as it would be blank, but should it be mentioned somehow anyway?

Answer (score 4):

No.  You did not attend and it should not be listed.